# Please help explain the use of particle を in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles

厳しい寒さの影響で西日本を中心に暖房用の電力の需要が高まり、

I’m quite confuse on the usage of particle を in this sentence. From my understanding, this を is marking the object which i think is 西日本 but i can’t find the verb that will be using with this 西日本　を. Please help enlighten me pls. Thanks in advance!

Ps.
This is the full paragraph.
厳しい寒さの影響で西日本を中心に暖房用の電力の需要が高まり、供給力に対する需要の割合を示す「使用率」は九州電力管内で97％、中国電力管内で98％まで上昇しました。